# Using a variable in awk to refer to a field's contents

Tags: linux, bash, awk

It may be duplicate question, as I saw many with same title, but I cant find the error in my script by those questions...

My file is

```
for (( c=15; c<=60; c++ ))
do 
while read -r i
do
   echo $i | awk -v var="$c" -F, 'var ~ /@/ {print $0}' >> $c.csv
done < asia.csv
done
```

when I run like `sh -x clean.sh`

it show

```
+ read -r i
+ awk -v var=15 -F, 'var ~ /@/ {print $0}'
+ echo bellerock-casino.asia,CSC Corporate Domains R25-ASIA '(299),dcs-admin@curacaohosting.com,,DNS1.CURACAOHOSTING.COM|DNS.CURACAOHOSTING.COM|DNS.CURACAOHOSTING.NET|,,20-Jan-2014' 15:34:56 UTC,01-Mar-2015 20:05:35 UTC,,2014-01-20 15:34:56 UTC,2015-03-01 20:05:35 UTC,CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED,2014-04-17 07:00:00 UTC,Registrant Name:Limited 'Cassini|Registrant' Organization:Cassini 'Limited|Registrant' Address:PO Box 606 Mezzanine 'West|Registrant' 'City:Gibraltar|Registrant' 'Country/Economy:GB|Registrant' Postal 'Code:1000|Registrant' 'Phone:+44.7624496408|Registrant' 'FAX:+44.1481822895|Registrant' E-mail:dcs-admin@curacaohosting.com,dcs-admin@curacaohosting.com,Limited Cassini,Cassini Limited,PO Box 606 Mezzanine West,,,,Gibraltar,,1000,UNITED KINGDOM,441481822895,,447624496408,,Administrative Name:Toohey 'Michael|Administrative' Organization:Australasian Gaming Specialists Pty 'Limited|Administrative' Address:3 Kimberley
```

for some reasons **inside the ' ' var won't print 15**

Any idea why so...

i.e. my script is checking if 15th field (and so on 16,17,18th) has @ or not... if it is the whole result should print in 15.csv

which is empty at the moment...

Comment: FYI, it would be _much_ faster to have just one copy of `awk` do all the work reading directly from `asia.csv`, instead of starting a separate copy of awk for each line in `asia.csv`, and doing _that_ 45 times.

Comment: Your `awk` code looks ok to me(not going for efficiency feedback here, since running `awk` in loop will be always slow, compare to passing variable/input to `awk` directly itself), what is the error you are seeing? Could you please elaborate more on same in your question, thank you.

Comment: That said, do note that `echo $i` is not the same as `echo "$i"`

Comment: ...anyhow, what do you mean "won't print 15"? Your code checks if `15` contains `@`; nothing in that code tries to print 15. (Indeed, `var ~ /@/` will never be true, because `var` will only contain numbers, and `@` is not a character found in a number).

Comment: Anyhow -- being more explicit about the desired behavior instead of assuming it's obvious to us what you meant your code to do when you were writing it would be helpful. We can read working code, but to read broken code requires getting inside the mind of the person who wrote it to infer their intent.

Comment: No, `var ~ /@/` doesn't check if the 15th field contains an @, it checks the value 15 contains an @.

Comment: ...also, please don't add asterisks for emphasis inside code segments. Code segments should only contain literal code and nothing else.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thxx, I was missing $ before var...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to check the 15th field instead of `15` itself, you should use `$var`, not just `var`.

```
awk -v var="$c" -F, '$var ~ /@/ {print $0}' <<<"$i" >>"$c.csv"
```

---

Consider shortening your loop to run awk only once per value of `c`, instead of once per line per value of `c`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for (( c=15; c<=60; c++ )); do 
  awk -v var="$c" -F, '$var ~ /@/ {print $0}' >"$c.csv" <asia.csv
done
```

Comment: or run awk only once total - `awk '{for (c=15;c<=60;c++) if ($c ~ /@/) print > (c".csv")}' asia.csv`.